# View is rising when keyboard is opened in react-native

Tags: react-native, keyboard

I have an issue when I open textInput keyboard the view in the bottom rises like this
I used `KeyboardAvoidingView` but I still encountering the same issue

[image]

and here is my implementation:

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView
      behavior={Platform.OS == 'ios' ? 'padding' : 'height'}
      style={{flex: 1, padding: wp(3.2)}}>
      <Design2 position="absolute" bottom={hp(0)} />
      <Design4 position="absolute" bottom={hp(0)} left={wp(25)} />
      <Text
        style={[
          Typography.darkTitle,
          {color: theme.textColor2},
          {marginVertical: hp(2.4)},
        ]}>
        {getMessageByKey('menu.title')}
      </Text>
      <Text style={[Typography.descriptionTextSmaller]}>
        {getMessageByKey('menu.change')}
      </Text>
      <View style={styles.menuImageContainer}>
        {menuImage ? (
          <FastImage style={styles.image} source={{uri: menuImage.uri}} />
        ) : (
          <FastImage
            style={{width: wp(38), height: wp(38)}}
            source={{uri: `${config.SERVER_URL}/menus/menu1.png`}}
          />
        )}
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.plusIcon}
          onPress={() => setMenuModalVisible(true)}>
          <PlusOrange />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>

      <View style={{justifyContent: 'center'}}>
        <Input
          placeholder={getMessageByKey('menu.menu_name')}
          value={menuName}
          onChangeText={(text) => {
            handleMenuNameChange(text);
          }}
        />
        {menuNameError && (
          <Text style={styles.menuNameError}>{menuNameError}</Text>
        )}
      </View>

      <RightArrow
        svg={isRTL() ? ArrowLeftWhite : WhiteRightArrow}
        onPress={onSubmit}
        style={[styles.rightButton]}
      />

      <MenuImageModal
        onChange={handleChange}
        isVisible={menuModalVisible}
        dismiss={() => {
          setMenuModalVisible(false);
        }}
      />
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

styles:

```
export const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: wp(3.2),
    marginTop: isIphoneX() ? hp(3) : 0,
  },
  avatarContent: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  menuImageContainer: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    marginTop: hp(10.46),
  },
  modalContent: {
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    position: 'absolute',
    width: wp(100),
    height: hp(49),
    bottom: wp(-5),
    left: wp(-5),

    borderTopLeftRadius: 30,
    borderTopRightRadius: 30,
    paddingBottom: wp(1),
  },
  row: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    height: hp(6),
    marginVertical: hp(0.3),
  },
  cameraIcon: {
    backgroundColor: Colors.red,
    width: wp(10),
    height: wp(10),
    borderRadius: 180,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',

    marginRight: wp(4),
  },
  icon: {
    width: wp(10),
    height: wp(10),
  },
  image: {
    width: wp(38),
    height: wp(38),
    borderRadius: 360,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F8F8F8',
  },
  plusIcon: {
    marginLeft: hp(13),
    bottom: hp(6),
    height: hp(5),
    width: hp(5),
  },
  viewSuggestions: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: hp(4.8),
    left: wp(55),
    zIndex: 999,
  },
  suggestionsTitle: {
    ...Typography.darkTitle,
    textAlign: 'center',
    marginBottom: hp(4),
    marginTop: hp(3),
  },
  suggestionsText: {
    ...Typography.descriptionText,
    color: 'black',
  },
  rightButton: {
    backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
    shadowColor: Colors.salmonOrange,
    right: wp(3),
    bottom: hp(7.0),
  },
  menuNameError: {
    ...Typography.inputErrorText,
    left: wp(1),
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is maybe not the best solution but it should work.
You can use this to get the height of the keyboard, change the height of the top div and then do it dynamically by seeing if the keyboards up or not.

**Gets Height of keyboard**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Keyboard, KeyboardEvent } from 'react-native';

export const useKeyboard = () => {
  const [keyboardHeight, setKeyboardHeight] = useState(0);

  function onKeyboardDidShow(e: KeyboardEvent) {
    setKeyboardHeight(e.endCoordinates.height);
  }

  function onKeyboardDidHide() {
    setKeyboardHeight(0);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow', onKeyboardDidShow);
    Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidHide', onKeyboardDidHide);
    return () => {
      Keyboard.removeListener('keyboardDidShow', onKeyboardDidShow);
      Keyboard.removeListener('keyboardDidHide', onKeyboardDidHide);
    };
  }, []);

  return keyboardHeight;
};
```

**Tells you wether keyboard is up or not**

```
const [isKeyboardVisible, setKeyboardVisible] = useState(false);

 useEffect(() => {
    const keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener(
      'keyboardDidShow',
      () => {
        setKeyboardVisible(true); // or some other action
      }
    );
    const keyboardDidHideListener = Keyboard.addListener(
      'keyboardDidHide',
      () => {
        setKeyboardVisible(false); // or some other action
      }
    );

    return () => {
      keyboardDidHideListener.remove();
      keyboardDidShowListener.remove();
    };
  }, []);
```